# Where is the Report Parameters Dialog Box

Tags: parameter-passing

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  I need to add a parameter to a local report.  All the information I have found says to use the Report Parameters Dialog Box.  Great!! It seems like I should select the rdlc file then the Report Menu option is displayed and I select the Dialog Box from the menu.  But it is not there.  Where is it? I have a code from a Microsoft example and can edit the XML if I need to but it looks like I should not need to.  Help!!

Answer (score 67):

I found it!!!!

You must have the rdlc open.
Press Ctrl+Atl+D to open the Report Data window (or select it from the view menu).
The parameters option is in the selection list.
Right-click it to add a new parameter.
Fill in the fields and select your options.

Ta-Da

Comment: It's the most stupid location of a dialog box! Hiding the Report Data window is a big fail. Stupid Microsoft.

Comment: Wasted an hour finding this. Phew!

Comment: Thank you, been looking for it!

Comment: Message for Microsoft : please invest some resources on interaction design!

Answer (score 8):

The Report Data window can also be found under the View menu item if your report is open. Seems like a weird location; I only found it because I stumbled across it.